# Is it possible to send an SMS message from SFMC without subscribing the user to a keyword?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, sms

Basically the title. We are looking to send to new users who signup via SMS. However, when the user signs up we prefer for them to not be subscribed to anything. Is this possible? I looked into sending via ServiceCloud but the less third party interactions the better.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe that is possible. Contacts must be subscribed to a key word for SFMC to run it's checks for compliance/spam reasons.

You can create a a single keyword only for sign up and have them subscribed to that only. Obviously you should avoid using that sign up keyword for any other sends.

You can then create a REST API process to unsubscribe that contact from that particular keyword if you want. Read this for a break down of exactly how to do that:
https://code4.cloud/articles/sfmc-unsubscribe-mobile-numbers-at-keyword-level-mobileconnect/

Once you have that code written out you could add it to a Script activity in Automation studio and schedule it periodically to unsubscribe new contacts that have signed up.